# How to show graph instead of tables?

Tags: javascript, html

Please I need help. I found really cool code: https://codepen.io/chris-creditdesign/pen/cypJf but after I put the code into one HTML file, I can only see the output as tables (there should be a graph)

What is wrong with the code ?

I saved the code from page into a single HTML file as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

HTML CODE HERE

<style>
CSS CODE HERE
</style>

<script>

JS CODE HERE
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but my result are tables (I expect graphs:)

Comment: Can you please share your code here

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting ACTUAL input and expected output.

Comment: Did you included these libraries in your code https://prnt.sc/nxc7l4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add to project additional library.

in your case it's

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js`

`https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js`

input these libraries before your code - in the head where the style also belongs

P.S.

In the future don't forget to watch the setting of `pen` project

**[image: strong text]**

Comment: I think we need to first take a look of the tried/sample code so to exactly pin point the solution.

Comment: @CodeReady We are all sure that was the problem

Comment: Great, thank you very much for help. This was really stupid mistake.

Comment: @Michal You are welcome, if helps you can select my answer like a correct.